# Date format issue in MS-EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have the date (MM/DD/YYYY) present in a cell of `general` format, which I intend to change them into date format of `dd-mmm-yyyy`. So I've formatted the cell as below:

[image]

The issue I am facing is that even on changing the cell format as above, the date is still remaining in the same format (MM/DD/YYYY) as :

[image]

But when I select and deselect the cell, the exact required format is appearing as below

[image]

I've thousand of rows in the sheet, I cannot individually select and deselect 
all the cells to get the desired format. Can you please provide simple solution for this..?

I am sharing the excel sheet with some sample data. Can you please have a look?

[CLICK HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZbA-TGzofIx-tUdmJwp3RtwiYT7losuF)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why that is happening, but perhaps try using Format Painter. Select a cell that has the format you desire, then format paint the range that you want to match that format.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, thanks for your reply, I've shared the excel sheet link. Can you please have a look..?

Comment: Generally people are unwilling/skeptical to download anything from this site. It is better to post a simplified example of your problem in your question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are stored as a number indicating the number of days that have elapsed since a reference date. So 1/1/1900 would be stored as 1 and TODAY() would be stored as 43359.

If your dates are still appearing as dates like 02/28/2020 even using General format, and if they are appearing left-justified, it would suggest that they are not being recognised as dates but rather as strings.

I can't explain the select/deselect behaviour, but you should be able to convert them into actual dates by selecting them and going to Data | Text to Columns. Then on the third screen of the wizard choose Date and MDY.

Then you should have actual dates and you should be able to format them however you would like them to be shown.